# Why won't my honor bar won't fill all the way?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

I've been playing RDR2 for a while, and I'm constantly doing things to increase honor, like helping people and being friendly, or tossing back fish into the lakes and ponds. Often I get the honor-up icon show on the right side of the screen.

But my honor level is stuck around 80%, and never goes up any more. If I do something bad, it will go down, and then come back up to 80% when I do good things, but that's where it maxes out like before.

Is this a bug, or is it supposed to be this way? If it's supposed to go up to 100% eventually, then something is wrong and I need to put in a ticket.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that honour is capped at ~80% until Chapter 6 according to various users on [GTA Forums](https://gtaforums.com/topic/919423-honor-level-wont-change/).

> **Darealbandicoot:** It's capped until Chapter 6 I believe.

Comment: I will try and find something a bit more official/concrete on this when I get the time.